# angular 4 - regular expression limit - show user to number of character left

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

I want to display message to user that to how many characters are left while typing. The regular expression is sending from server and here are some regular expression examples which are sending from server.

`^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-. ()]{1,25}$`
`^(void|[0-9]{0,20})$`

once user started typing i want to show message with "Number of character is left {{count}}" and once limit(max length from regx) is reached it should not allow user to enter any character in input. I try with this regx to find out limit in regx `(/\^[(.*)]{([0-9]+),([0-9]+)}\$/i)` and match it with the string but this pattern is not working with all regx..

How i Can achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just check the strings `length` ?

Comment: Obviously you don't follow the basics. It's not clear by `[(.*)]` what you tried to impress. If all characters fall into calculating length you don't need regular expressions at all, otherwise you need to match all within-the-scope characters using `g` modifier and calculate length.

Comment: If you want to count only non-white-space characters, do `str.match(/\S/g).length`

Comment: @revo but i want to get max length from regular expression and then only i can check the count which is enterred by user

Comment: @joelkornbluh Edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution

1. Get regular expression from server
2. Find maximum length you need to restrict user to
3. Use input element .length property to get length of current user input and then show it to user
4. If it is less than maximum length it is fine if not then remove last n characters where n is length-max characters from input string

You dont need to match it with regex to restrict a string's length as pointed out in many comments. Keep it simple so you can understand and maintain it later as well.

Comment: as you mention in second point how to fetch maximum length from regular expression which is sending from server.. because for different input there is different regx and it contains different maxlength

Comment: I think all of your server regex scripts would have length restriction written at the end like {0,25}. You can pickup the last opening and closing curly brackets and split the inner part with string to get length.